# How to calculate whether a series is convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If a series is given for example
$1 - 1/2 + 1/4-1/8+1/16-1/32+...$ up-to infinity
how to check whether the series converges or diverges?

Is there any particular formula?

Comment: @Vega the ratio is $-1/2$

Comment: @Andrei oops a typo!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series), meaning the terms are of form $$a, ar, ar^2, ...$$
In your particular case $a=1$ and $r=-1/2$. This series is convergent if $|r|<1$. The link provided also shows you that the sum is
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty ar^k=\frac a{1-r}$$

Comment: This is right if we assume that the sequence in OP follows the pattern. But nothing tells us what there is after $-1/32$, so the question is not well posed